Triggering the slave node to checkout code through Jenkins failed, but executing commands directly on the slave was successful
I have a Jenkins pipeline task to compile code and package it for execution on the slave node. The assembly line task script is as follows:
scmVars = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [[name: commitID]],
                        browser: bitbucketServer("http://***/projects/projectname/repos/projectname/"),
                        extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 1200, honorRefspec: true],
                                    [$class: 'BuildChooserSetting',
                                        buildChooser: [$class: 'DefaultBuildChooser']],
                                    [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                                    relativeTargetDir: '{projectname}'],
                                    [$class: 'LocalBranch',
                                        localBranch: "**"],
                                    [$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                                        disableSubmodules: false,
                                        parentCredentials: true,
                                        recursiveSubmodules: true,
                                        reference: '',
                                        trackingSubmodules: false,
                                        timeout: 1200]],
                        gitTool: 'Default',
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[refspec: refSpec, url: 'ssh://git@****:7999/projectname/projectname.git']]
                    ])

Using gitscm to pull code, execution failed with the following exception message:
ERROR: Execution failed
08:08:09
hudson. plugins.git.GitException: Command "C: \Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe submodule update -init -recursive
gemp_gst" returned status code 1:
08:08:09
stdout:
08:08:09
stderr: Cloning into 'path'…
08:08:09
Host key verification failed.
08: 08:09
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Directly logging into the slave node and using the cmd command to pull the code was successful
git clone ssh://git@***:7999/projectname.git

cloning into 'projectname'
done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1324/1324), done.
Receiving objects: 12% (133671/1049750), 445.31 мів 8.08 MiB/s


Your Jenkins runs under a different user than what you log in as manually, therefore they have different known_hosts files and trust different hosts. You have two options:

Log in as the same user as Jenkins and manually do the first clone, triggering the prompt to accept the host key and add it permanently to Jenkins known_hosts
Go to Jenkins web UI, Manage, Security, Git Host Key Verification Configuration, and select "Accept first connection"

Then just re-run your pipeline and everything should be hunky-dory. Or at least you get a different error message.
